# Why does useQuery call cause a re-render in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo

As we know a react component is re-rendered when it's props or state changes.

Now i'm using `useQuery` from `react-apollo` package like below:

```
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const getBookQuery = gql`
  {
    books {
      name
    }
  }
`;

function BookList() {
    const { loading, error, data} = useQuery(getBookQuery);

    if(loading) return <p>Loading....</p>
    if(error) return <p>Ops! Something went wrong</p>

    return (
      <>
        <ul>
          {data.books.map(book => (
            <li key={book.name}>{book.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </>
    )
}

export default BookList;
```

When i run the code above, we first get `Loading...` in DOM which is then updated to list containing query data (once it arrives). But how does react know to re-render my component once data is received from query.

Are these `data`, `loading` and `error` properties mapped to component props and they are updating? If so, why doesn't chrome dev tools show any props for this `BookList` component?

[image]

Can someone explain how is this `useQuery` custom hook working here?

Comment: Documentations are for these purposes right? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/

Comment: You can't see the props, but you can see the hooks, below the props. 
Apollo has a very good developer tool btw. You can use that, too

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A good way of figuring out (roughly) what is happening in `useQuery` is to consider how you'd do it yourself, e.g.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const data = await GraphQL.request(getBookQuery);
      setData(data);
    } catch (ex) {
      setError(ex);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  if(loading) return <p>Loading....</p>
  if(error) return <p>Ops! Something went wrong</p>

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.books.map(book => (
          <li key={book.name}>{book.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

In the above you can see your component has *state* (not props) `data`, `loading` and `error` which causes your component to re-render.

You can then imagine this logic was wrapped in your own `useQuery` hook:

```js
const useQuery = (query, variables) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const data = await GraphQL.request(query, variables);
      setData(data);
    } catch (ex) {
      setError(ex);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return { data, loading, error };
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(getBookQuery);

  if(loading) return <p>Loading....</p>
  if(error) return <p>Ops! Something went wrong</p>

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.books.map(book => (
          <li key={book.name}>{book.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

So ultimately your component is re-rendering because it does have `data`, `loading` and `error` held in `MyComponent` state, it's just abstracted away.

Comment: Ah so basically a hook's state variable also works as a state (or prop?) for component where hook was used? If hook's state changes component render also gets triggered. Tested it using a very basic custom hook and seems like that is actually the case `https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-sea-ghqjm`.

Comment: Yeah, there's actually no such thing as a 'hooks' state but only a components state, a custom hook merely defines state associated with the component it's called from. The fact useState is called within a different function (useQuery) is largely meaningless, it's all related to the component from which it was called in.

Answer (score 2):

Hooks can have their own state which when changed can trigger a rerender. E.g loading, error, data.

I created a sample implementation of the useQuery hook of apollo in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wave-dd1wd?file=/src/BookList2.js

In the fake implementation it's visible that the hook has state and whenever the state changes the component re-renders.

Also created another component BookList2 where instead of using the hook I pasted the fake implementation of the hook in the component - that way maybe it'll be clearer how the re-render is triggered

**TLDR: Check https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wave-dd1wd?file=/src/BookList2.js - see that hooks can have state which when changed can cause rerenders**

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is the default configuration of you `useQuery()` hook which is provided by the `QueryClient`. For example rerendering on window focus is a default setting, which causes the hook to refetch and therefore rerender on every window focus (for example when clicking on devtools and click back into the DOM. You can manipulate this when creating the queryClient.

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      //other query settings
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
});
```

There are other [settings](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/QueryClient) to have in the back of your head.